# Объясните, почему это работает?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Нашел css код который даёт нам резиновый квадрат с фиксированными пропорциями. т.е. квадрат остаётся квадратом как мы бы не изменяли ширину бразура. Я не могу понять, почему див в значение **высоты** принимает значение **ширины**?

```css
div {
  width: 50%;
  /* Задаём ширину */
  margin: auto;
  /* Размещаем по цетру */
  background: silver;
  /* Задаём фон */
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Скрываем всё, что выходит за границы*/
}

div:before {
  /* Добавляем свойства в конец элемента */
  content: "";
  padding-top: 100%;
  /* Отступ сверху */
  float: left;
  /* Приковываем к левому краю */
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: div:width 10vw height 10vw - тоже делает блок квадратным

Comment: _/* Добавляем свойства в конец элемента */_ - в начало, потому и before

Comment: а где место, про которое ты говоришь _див в значение высоты принимает значение ширины_? В приведенном css не указана высота

Comment: Присоеденяюсь к @Grundy, не вижу места места про которое говорится в вопросе :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как указано в [спецификации](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-top#Values):

> значение отступа, указанное в процентах, рассчитывается относительно ширины содержащего блока.

Таким образом, задав `padding-top: 100%` мы распираем элемент before, и, как следствие, сам div, на 100% ширины дива, что позволяет получить в итоге квадратный вид.